# What is the cardinality of the set of all real closed intervals whose midpoint is a rational number?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let A be the set of all real closed intervals whose midpoint is a rational number:
A={[a,b]| $a,b∈R ,a+b/2∈Q$}.
From here i did not how to define a function to prove it.

Comment: $$\{[-x, x]\mid x\in\mathbb R\}\subset A\subset\{[x, x+q]\mid x\in\mathbb R,\;q\in\mathbb Q\}$$

Answer (score 1):

I would start by simplifying the problem: let's fix a rational number, say $q = 0$, and decide how many real closed intervals have $q$ as their midpoint I'll denote this by $A_q$). In other words, the cardinality of $A_q$ is how many intervals are there of the form $[-x,x], x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer:

> $|A_0| = |\mathbb{R}|$

Once we have that, observe that the problem has translational symmetry: if $p,q$ are rational numbers, then $|A_q| = |A_p|$. Moreover, $A_q \cap A_p = \emptyset$ if $p \neq q$ and $A = \cup_{q \in \mathbb{Q}} A_q$, so
$$ |A| = \sum_{q \in \mathbb{Q}} |A_q| = |A_0| \cdot |\mathbb{Q}|.$$
From here, once you know $|A_0|$ you have the answer.

Hope this helps!